# Duplicate lines beginning with "x", replacing "x" in the duplicate with "y"?

Tags: regular-expression, search

I have a file with the following pattern:

```
foo 111
baz
foo 222
baz
foo 333
baz
```

which needs to be turned into

```
foo 111
bar 111
baz
foo 222
bar 222
baz
foo 333
bar 333
baz
```

So, duplicate all the lines beginning with `foo`, and change only `foo` in the duplicate but leave the rest of the line (which differs in each case) intact. How to do this?

Comment: If you aren't hell-bound on a regexp, a macro will do just fine. Doesn't really matter much in simple cases like this, but if you have something a bit more complicated it's a very valid alternative.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here you go:

```
:g/foo/t.|s//bar
```

Decomposing:

```
:g/foo/    " start a global command applied on all lines matching 'foo'
t.         " duplicate the current line (the cursor is now on the new line)
|          " chain a new command
s//bar     " substitute the last searched element with 'bar'
```

Because the `g` command will update the search pattern, so you can omit the pattern to replace in the substitute command. (ref: `:h :g`, search for `search pattern`).

---

**Older version:**

```
:g/foo/norm! yyp:s/foo/bar^M
```

Decomposing:

```
:g            start a global command
/foo/         apply only on lines having 'foo'
norm!         execute a normal command
yyp           duplicate the line
:s//bar       replace foo with bar on the line (the duplicated one)
^M            add enter to execute the substitution
```

To insert the `^M` press <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd>.

**Note**: I originally came up with the "older" version, before I learned about the `t` command. I'll leave it but I won't recommend using it. The first one is cleaner more straightforward.

Comment: Solved, the 'simpler version' worked perfectly. The first version however, resulted in the duplicate line still beginning with `foo`....

Comment: strange, did you entered `^M` as I explained ?

Comment: My bad, didn't read that well. First solution works as well!

Comment: I don't know why you bother including the complicated version at all.  The simpler version is...simpler.  ;)  (Not to mention being POSIX compliant.)  Why not put it first?

Comment: Initially I came up with the first version, which was more natural to me, because at the time I was not aware of `t`, and then I added the second one. I'll change the order, you are right. How about the first one being POSIX ?

Answer (score 1):

I do stuff like this all the time and just do something like `%s/^foo \(.*\)/foo \1\rbar \1/` (partially because I also do a lot of similar tasks that can't be turned into something clever using a copy function, and `\(.*\)` is part of my muscle memory by now).

I suspect it's not POSIX-compliant (it doesn't work on other vi clones), but using `^M` (<kbd>C-V</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>) instead of `\r` seems to work on most other vi clones.